# Setting Google Chrome as a default Brower

Tags: android, cordova

Can we set Chrome as a default browser on the coding side( client side ) in Android( 4.1 , 4.2 , 4.3) so that the webview inside a hybrid application ( HTML application packed through phonegap )is also opened in Google Chrome by default ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we set Chrome as a default browser on the coding side

No.

First, you cannot make any app be the user's default. The user chooses what the user's default is.

Second, Chrome may or may not exist on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you achieve your task. I draw this conclusion before reading below link :-

[To open settings page of chrome browser in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059478/to-open-settings-page-of-chrome-browser-in-android-programmatically)

[How can i set the Google Chrome as a default browser of the application that i make programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496788/how-can-i-set-the-google-chrome-as-a-default-browser-of-the-application-that-i-m)